# How do I replace multi-line comments with single-line comments in a Java file using sed?

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Suppose I have the following file called `Test.java`:

```
import java.io.*;

/* test comment */
public class Test { /* another test comment */
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Java programs can contain single-line `//` comments and multi-line `/* ... */` comments. What I am trying to accomplish is to find `/* ... */` comments in `Test.java` that occupy a single line and replaces them with a `//` comment, in place. So, after replacement, `Test.java` should look like this:

```
import java.io.*;

// test comment
public class Test { // another test comment
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

I tried to do this with `sed` by doing the following:

```
sed -ri 's//\* ([.]*[ ]*) \*//// \1/' Test.java
```

However, it doesn't seem to change anything. Due to this, I was wondering how do I just replace comments while keeping the rest of the line unchanged? I'm unsure how to accomplish this behavior. I think my regex is off somehow, but I'm not entirely sure why. Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
sed 's_/\*\(.*\)\*/_//\1_' <Test.java
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- I'm using the `_` as a delimiter so I don't have to escape the `/`
  characters
- '/*' is matched with `/\*` (escaping the *)
- I remember the stuff in between the above using `\(` and `\)`
- then replace with '//' (no need to escape) and the remembered content `\1`

Once you've confirmed it does what you want, just add the `-i` and remove the
`<`:

```
sed -i 's_/\*\(.*\)\*/_//\1_' Test.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your second bullet point was meant to be:

```
'/*' is matched with /\* (escaping the *) and '*/' is matched with \*/
```